# Optimizing Subset selection algorithm to compare solutions within a deviation

Tags: c#, algorithm, subset

I'm currently using a algorithm to find the element(s) (unsigned decimals) which sum is the closest to a specified value `target`.
EDIT: Elements can only be used once.

```
private class Solution
{
    public int StartIndex;
    public int EndIndex;
    public decimal Sum;
    public int Length
    {
        get { return EndIndex - StartIndex + 1; }
    }

}

public static List<decimal> Solve(List<decimal> elements, decimal target)
{
    Solution bestSolution = new Solution { StartIndex = 0, EndIndex = -1, Sum = 0 };
    decimal bestError = Math.Abs(target);
    Solution currentSolution = new Solution { StartIndex = 0, Sum = 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
    {
        currentSolution.EndIndex = i;
        currentSolution.Sum += elements[i];

        while (elements[currentSolution.StartIndex] <= currentSolution.Sum - target)
        {
            currentSolution.Sum -= elements[currentSolution.StartIndex];
            ++currentSolution.StartIndex;
        }

        decimal currentError = Math.Abs(currentSolution.Sum - target);
        if (currentError < bestError || currentError == bestError && currentSolution.Length < bestSolution.Length)
        {
            bestError = currentError;
            bestSolution.Sum = currentSolution.Sum;
            bestSolution.StartIndex = currentSolution.StartIndex;
            bestSolution.EndIndex = currentSolution.EndIndex;
        }
    }

    return elements.GetRange(bestSolution.StartIndex, bestSolution.Length);
}
```

Existing more than one solutions, I need to get the one with the less elements.
I've been analyzing the code but can not conclude whether that is the case.

Even better, but probably more difficult to accomplish would be to select the solution with less elements within a range.

Eg:

```
Target value = 50.00
Solution A: 4 elements => 50.00
Solution B: 3 elements => 49.99
solution C: 2 element  => 49.90    ««« PREFERABLE (Less elements within a given 0.50 deviation )
Solution D: 1 elements => 49.30
```

I'm looking for help on how to optimize this algorithm to accomplish the changes above. Thanks!

Comment: If this is already working then it belongs on codereview site.

Comment: @deathismyfriend I seriously doubt that the question for an alternative algorithm belongs to codereview site.

Comment: You only look at a sub-sequence, right? Not an arbitrary combination of the values in the list?

Comment: You code doesn't seem to honor the deviation factor yet. If you put it in then you could iterate starting with the solution that has the least number of elements and go on until you hit a result that satisfies the deviation limit.

Comment: Question: Can elements be used more than once?

Comment: Elements can only be used once

Comment: I think I saw this (or something very similar) here some time ago - and I ask you the same I asked them: how do you solve the problem with the *deviation*? (for example: would 1 element with 49.81 be even better?

Comment: @Carster Yes, because 1 element with 49.81 would be closer to the target

Answer (score 1):

Try a recursive algorithm.  The code at level 0 tries 10, 20, 30, 40.  At level 2 tried two numbers like 10, 20 then 10, 30, and then 10, 40.  The code has a feature that is stops trying when at a level the sum is greater than the target.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<decimal> inputs = new List<decimal> { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
            int startIndex = 0;
            decimal target = 50;
            Solution solution = new Solution(inputs);
            List<decimal> elements = new List<decimal>();
            solution.Solve(elements, target, startIndex);
        }

        public class Solution
        {
            private List<decimal> inputs = null;
            private static bool first = true;
            public static decimal Sum = -1;
            public static decimal error = -1;
            public static List<decimal> elements { get; set; }

            public Solution(List<decimal> inputs)
            {
                elements = new List<decimal>();
                this.inputs = new List<decimal>(inputs);
                this.inputs.Sort();
            }
            public static bool BestSolution(List<decimal> newSolution, decimal target)
            {
                bool higher = false;
                if(first == true)
                {
                    AddSolution(newSolution, target);
                    first = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    decimal newError = Math.Abs(newSolution.Sum() - target);
                    if(newError < error)
                    {
                        AddSolution(newSolution, target);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if((newError == error) && (newSolution.Count < elements.Count))
                        {
                            AddSolution(newSolution, target);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(elements.Sum() >= target) higher = true;
                return higher;
            }
            private static void AddSolution(List<decimal> newSolution, decimal target)
            {
                Sum = newSolution.Sum();
                error = Math.Abs(newSolution.Sum() - target);
                elements = new List<decimal>(newSolution);
            }
            public void Solve(List<decimal> localElements, decimal target, int startIndex)
            {
                for (int i = startIndex; i < inputs.Count; i++)
                {
                    List<decimal> newElements = new List<decimal>(localElements);
                    newElements.Add(inputs[i]);
                    bool higher = Solution.BestSolution(newElements, target);
                    if (!higher)
                    {
                        Solve(newElements, target, i + 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```